# MemoryError when I merge two Pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, merge, out-of-memory

I searched almost all over the internet and somehow none of the approaches seem to work in my case.

I have two large csv files (each with a million+ rows and about 300-400MB in size). They are loading fine into data frames using the *read_csv* function without having to use the *chunksize* parameter.
I even performed certain minor operations on this data like new column generation, filtering, etc.

However, when I try to merge these two frames, I get a **MemoryError**. I have even tried to use SQLite to accomplish the merge, but in vain. The operation takes forever.

Mine is a Windows 7 PC with 8GB RAM. The Python version is 2.7

Thank you.

Edit: I tried chunking methods too. When I do this, I don't get MemoryError, but the RAM usage explodes and my system crashes.

Comment: What code are you using to merge them?

Comment: merge_df = pandas.merge(df1, df2, left_on = "Colname1", right_on = "Colname2")

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit version of Python?

Comment: Yes. I'm using a 64-bit Python 2.7. Currently, Anaconda 4.3 (with Spyder 3) is installed on my system.

Comment: Could you paste the first few rows of each dataframe? Chances are, you're doing a merge that is different from the operation you intended. (From my experience, most join operations involving dataframes less than 1GB complete in a time scale of seconds, but of course this depends on the kind of join as well as the structure of the data.)

Comment: I'm sorry, it's confidential data. Could you please explain your statement, "you're doing a merge that is different from the operation you intended". And yes, even I have handled bigger files before. That is why I'm clueless about the issue.

Comment: Suppose you have a data set with ten rows, 5 of them take the value `'A'`, 5 are `'B'` in the joining column. If you join this dataset with itself on this joining column, your result has 50 rows, or is 5 times as large. There's a chance that there was some additional column that you should be joining on, but forgot to include.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Ken. But, I don't think that is the issue because I made sure that both the joining columns have all unique values.

Comment: You were right, @KenWei I made a big blunder in creating distinct values for my joining column.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

When you are merging data using pandas.merge it will use df1 memory, df2 memory and merge_df memory. I believe that it is why you get a memory error. You should export df2 to a csv file and use chunksize option and merge data.

It might be a better way but you can try this.
*for large data set you can use chunksize option in pandas.read_csv

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("yourdata.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("yourdata2.csv")
df2_key = df2.Colname2

# creating a empty bucket to save result
df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=(df1.columns.append(df2.columns)).unique())
df_result.to_csv("df3.csv",index_label=False)

# save data which only appear in df1 # sorry I was doing left join here. no need to run below two line.
# df_result = df1[df1.Colname1.isin(df2.Colname2)!=True]
# df_result.to_csv("df3.csv",index_label=False, mode="a")

# deleting df2 to save memory
del(df2)

def preprocess(x):
    df2=pd.merge(df1,x, left_on = "Colname1", right_on = "Colname2")
    df2.to_csv("df3.csv",mode="a",header=False,index=False)

reader = pd.read_csv("yourdata2.csv", chunksize=1000) # chunksize depends with you colsize

[preprocess(r) for r in reader]
```

this will save merged data as df3.

Comment: Yes, if you wanna do inner join you do not need to do


     # save data which only appear in df1
     df_result = df1[df1.Colname1.isin(df2.Colname2)!=True]
     df_result.to_csv("df3.csv",index_label=False, mode="a")

Comment: I think the statement  to create the df2.csv file is missing.

Comment: I'm sorry you need just need to load "yourdata2.csv" with chunksize option

Comment: 1.Before running the loop have you released all the unnecessary object using del(object)? 2. if so could you try to do it by few rows of df2 and all rows of df1?*just in case for you are joining with the correct row and check the result is as expected.

Comment: I used larger chunks before, Tomohiro. My bad. I'm trying with smaller chunks (1000 as you suggested), and I'm currently awaiting output. Thanks.

Comment: Hope it works! BTW I think you can use 10000 or more (depends on number of column though...)

Comment: On every iteration in the loop you are merging the chunksize of df2 with the full df1? isnt that excessive? also in the preprocess function I would call the df `df3`.

Comment: This answer saved me much time and consternation. Thanks!

Comment: why this assignment df2_key = df2.Colname2

Comment: Did you forget the `df3` assignment?

Comment: In the case where df2 is too large to load into memory, you can retrieve the columns only with: df2_column_names = pd.read_csv("yourdata2.csv", nrows=0).columns.tolist()
This is also a faster if df2 takes a while to load for some reason.

Comment: How are you deleting df2 before using it on the merge? How are you getting the df2 data to merge with df1?

Comment: I tried this but it is very slow, it will take about 6-7 hours on the 8.7 mil rows dataframe x 300 000 rows dataframe. Any ideas how to speed this up?

Answer (score 6):

The reason you might be getting `MemoryError: Unable to allocate..` could be due to duplicates or blanks in your dataframe. Check the column you are joining on (when using merge) and see if you have duplicates or blanks. If so get rid of them using this command:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset ='column_name', keep = False, inplace = True)
```

Then re-run your python/pandas code.  This worked for me.

Comment: nice one! some variant or this worked for me as well. I actually had duplicates in the indexes because I had to round down ms timestamps to s in a previous step.

Answer (score 4):

In general chunk version suggested by @T_cat works great.

However, memory exploding might be caused by joining on columns that have `Nan` values.
So you may want to exclude those rows from the join.

see: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24698#issuecomment-614347153

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the left data frame has NaN in the merging columns which causes the final merged dataframe to bloat.

Fill the merging column in the left data frame with zeros if ok.

```
df['left_column'] = df['left_column'].fillna(0)
```

Then do the merge. See what you get.