# How to perform a merge of (too) large dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to merge couple of dataframes from [HomeCredit Kaggle competion according to the data schema](https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-credit-default-risk/data).
I did following:

```
train = pd.read_csv('~/Documents/HomeCredit/application_train.csv')
bureau = pd.read_csv('~/Documents/HomeCredit/bureau.csv')
bureau_balance = pd.read_csv('~/Documents/HomeCredit/bureau_balance.csv')

train = train.merge(bureau,how='outer',left_on=['SK_ID_CURR'],right_on=['SK_ID_CURR'])
train = train.merge(bureau_balance,how='inner',left_on=['SK_ID_BUREAU'],right_on=['SK_ID_BUREAU'])
```

which fails at

> MemoryError

for the second merge.
The train data frame is of shape (308k,122), bureau (1.72M,12) and bureau_balance (27.3M,3). It is my understanding that an application from the train df does not have to have a record in burea table but all rows from that table should have a record in  bureau_balance.

I'm running the code at my local instance with 16GB RAM.

Is there a way how to cope around the memory issue with such a large dataset?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this approach at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386405/memoryerror-when-i-merge-two-pandas-data-frames ?

Comment: @EnayatRajabi That's excatly my issue. Thanks.

Comment: try chunk loading from df saved to disk

Comment: Could I possibly use sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a certain problem size pandas is not the appropriate tool. I would import the data in a relational database and issue SQL queries. Sqlalchemy is a nice python tool for working with databases.

Comment: Just have read the answer... It's funny you wrote that because that's excatly what I'm doing now. I'm importing one file by one into my local SQL Server database.