# How to optimize a join with a big pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I try made a filter in a dataframes with this code bellow but I have get this error `numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 31.4 MiB for an array with shape (16452481,) and data type int16`, because this dataframes is realy big, how can I optimize this code to use less RAM memory?

** I could use SQL to

Give me any suggestions!?

```
# attempt 1
df = df[(df["NE_STATUS"].notna()) | (df["NUMERO_CTRC_COMP"].notna())]

# attempt 2
df.drop(df[(df["NE_STATUS"].isna()) | (df["NUMERO_CTRC_COMP"].isna())], inplace = True)

>>>df.info()
Int64Index: 16503693 entries, 0 to 566975
Columns: 103 entries, SIGLA_EMPRESA to NE_STATUS
dtypes: category(99), object(4)
memory usage: 3.9+ GB
```

Comment: Maybe you could start by first carefully examining the memory consumption of the dataframe with df.memory_usage(deep=True)

Answer (score 0):

Since Pandas will put all the three dataframes in memory (sources + result) there is no easy way to reduce consumption.
A good solution is described below by exporting the dataframes in csv and read them in chunks
[MemoryError when I merge two Pandas data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386405/memoryerror-when-i-merge-two-pandas-data-frames)