# Pandas merge on calculation [Memory Error]

Tags: python, pandas, memory, merge

I have two big tables A and B I need to merge in pandas.
I need to merge them on a calculation rule:
A.long * B.larg < 1

I can't manage to do something like this as I have a memory error du to size of both table:

```
A['tmp'] = 0
B['tmp'] = 0
C = pd.merge(A, B, how='inner', on = ['tmp'])
C = C[C[long * larg] < 1]
```

I would like to do something like:

```
C = pd.merge(A, B, how='inner', on = [A['long']*B['larg'] <1])
```

But it doesn't work.
Do you know how I could do?
Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried to read the data in chunks? Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47387088/14234692) about why and how to do that

Comment: Why don't you calculate the key for the merge first and then merge on it?